# Git rebase - Multiple git requests for solving merge conflicts on the same files

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

In order to keep a cleaner history I was trying to do a [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

I had several commits in my branch and I wanted to squash them when doing the rebase.

**Wanted outcome:**

Go from that:

```
Master      A-B
            \
MyBranch     1-2-3-4-5-...-10-..-20
```

To that:

```
Master      A-B-C
```

**The Scenario**

I started from branching from commit `A` in the master and working on my branch:

```
Master      A
            \
MyBranch     1-2-3-4-5-...-10
```

While I was working on my branch, another commit `B` was done in master:

```
Master      A-B
            \
MyBranch     1-2-3-4-5-...-10
```

To have a good CI, I started by merging the `B` commit into the `myBranch` and solved all the conflicts that I had:

```
Master      A-B
            \  \
             |  ----------- merge
             |             \
MyBranch     1-2-3-4-5-...-10
```

Then I had several more commits in my branch:

```
Master      A-B
            \  \
             |  ----------- merge
             |             \
MyBranch     1-2-3-4-5-...-10-...-20
```

Then I started the `rebase -i` (using Intellij).

At this phase I thought that no more merge request will show up, as `B` is merged into `myBranch`.

But then, Intellij asked to to merge again the same files I already merged before.

And when I solved all the conflict, he asked me to do it again. and again. and again. On the same files over and over.

It seems like for every commit (or chunk of commits) out of the `1 - 20`  commits, I needed to solve the merge conflict again.

Only after solving the conflicts for something like 7 times, the operation ended.

Is there something that I'm missing here in order to avoid this pit hole?

Answer (score 1):

A plain `rebase -i` simply ignores merge commits. This explains why you had to do the same conflict resolution during rebasing that you already did during merging. Also, once there is a merge conflict during rebasing, it will be repeated with each subsequent commit that affects the same files.

To avoid the problem you could try a `git rebase --preserve-merges`.